# opensource projects for privilege management feature in asp.net MVC site?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, open-source

my data-driven web site needs a `visualized` Privilege Management feature,

but i don't want to develop it by hand, i think there must be some mature general projects.

i use `asp.net mvc`, `razor`, `EF` & `MySql`

if not `role-based` but `permission-based` will be better

Comment: Just to confirm: as "Privilege Management feature" you mean something related to ["Privilege Management Infrastructure"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_Management_Infrastructure)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov no,   'visualized' meaning a page can config user's privileges which are general CRUD operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my code:

```
public class PermissionsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly Permission _requiredPermission;

    public PermissionsAttribute(string itemName, Operation op)
    {
        var permi = new Permission()
        this._requiredPermission = permi;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var user = HttpContext.Current.User;
        if (user == null)
        {/*redirect to sign-in page*/}
        else
        {/*check permission/*}
    }
```

just add this attribute to Controller and action

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [nuget](http://nuget.org/packages?q=membership)

I have used [Security Guard](https://github.com/kahanu/Security-Guard/wiki/1.--Overview), it works fine, and has some above basic graphics and features. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11809783/985284